# Yellow pilot light on infrared heater

Tags: heater

I am using an LP infrared Dyna Glo 30,000btu heater with Mr.Heater dual regulator, and 100lb tank.
After needing to get a refill and buy a second 100lb tank for a backup, the pilot light on the heater was burning yellow. Thinking this might be an issue with dirt in the pilot, I cleaned it out. No change, hooking up my backup heater (same brand and model) for the first time, same issue yellow pilot flame. I replaced the dual regulator (same brand and model) this came with new hoses and connections.

Comment: The only part that remained the same was the gas in the tanks, both were filled at the same place at the same time.

Comment: (Note: My first tank was overfilled on the previous fill, but after draining off the excess had no issue.) Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like either a valve after the regulator isn't open, or the regulator is wrong, or a pipe got kinked during the replacement, or some crud got into the system and is blocking flow... Or you are burning the wrong gas.

Comment: Try hooking up the heater(s) temporarily to a BBQ propane tank that was not filled by the same propane filling station. You can't run a 30K BTU heater for long on a BBQ tank due to bulk propane temperature / pressure considerations, but you can run it long enough to purge the existing propane from the heater and check the color of the pilot flame. If you get a normal blue flame from the BBQ tank, the recently refilled propane is bad. If you still get a yellow flame, look for another cause.